# Kotlin how to write two conditionals inside one modifier

Tags: kotlin, if-statement, android-jetpack-compose

How to write two conditionals under one Modifier? For example for `.background` i have one conditional that handles pressed state and other is just for setting background color depending of passed variants.
If code is written with two `.background` modifier then isPressed part is not working.

```
 Box(
  Modifier
     .pointerInput(Unit) {
       detectTapGestures(
        onPress = {
         try {
             isPressed = true
             awaitRelease()
         } finally {
           isPressed = false
          }
        },
       )
      }
.background(if (!isPressed) Red else DarkRed)
.background(if (variant == VariantButtons.Primary) Red else if (variant == VariantButtons.Green)  Green else Color.Transparent)
)
```

Comment: It looks like you should just create a variable and define this in a whole other block of code with more ifs that don't have to be inline.  That said, it's not clear what you _want_ the behavior to be -- what _should_ happen if, say, `isPressed` is false and `variant` is Gray?

Comment: If IsPressed true and false changes the background color. And also the background color changes depending of variants that i pass from outside.

Comment: @Codeanorr which is the order/priority?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you can use only one background modifier and combine statements inside it, just like below:

```
.background(
    if (isPressed) {
        DarkRed
    } else {
        when (variant) {
            VariantButtons.Primary -> Red
            VariantButtons.Green -> Green
            else -> Color.Transparent
        }
    }
)
```